# Android network connection

Tags: android, networking

Could someone please explain why I'm getting the error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.project/com.project.Deals}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
```

When I am using the two classes below, been doing this for ages now. I appreciate the help

```
public class Deals extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView textview = new TextView(this);
        textview.setText("This is the Artists tab");
        setContentView(textview);

        NetworkConnection nc = new NetworkConnection();
        boolean networkAvail = nc.isNetworkConnAvail();
        if (networkAvail == true){
        }

    }
};

public class NetworkConnection extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

public boolean isNetworkConnAvail() {

        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) 
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null)
            return networkInfo.isConnected();

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your NetworkConnection class you never call onCreate try this instead:

```
public boolean isNetworkConnAvail(Context context) {

    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) 
        context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null)
        return networkInfo.isConnected();

    return false;
}
```

And call it like this from your other class:

```
nc.isNetworkConnAvail(this);
```

Or alternatively call the onCreate method of the super class in your constructor in NetworkConnection. If you are only extending Activity for the sake of being able to use getSystemService then you may as well not extend Activity and just have the Context passed through either in the constructor or in the method itself as this will then give you access to those methods :)

Comment: Thanks very new to android, I appreciate the help, voted you as #1 :)

Comment: @James You're very welcome! Make sure to read what amp said too about the permissions in the manifest file. Accessing different resources on the device will require you setup the appropriate permissions in the manifest file.

Comment: Don't worry I made sure I had those after watching 'thenewboston' on youtube and his 200 videos on Android!

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

And remove this:

```
extends Activity
```

in `class NetworkConnection`

**Update**

Better idea is to change your code to:

```
public class Deals extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

boolean networkAvail = isNetworkConnAvail();
if (networkAvail == true){
  //do something
}

}

public boolean isNetworkConnAvail() {

ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) 
    getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (networkInfo != null)
    return networkInfo.isConnected();

return false;
}

}
```

`

Comment: Thanks for your help I appreciate it, I got it working thanks to the post above but +1 though :)